# How to download the Test plan/ case in Kiwi TCMS

Tags: kiwi-tcms

KIWI TCMS has a feature to print the test plan or test cases. Is there any feature like that to download the test plan or test cases in any of xml,csv,json formats?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such feature in Kiwi TCMS and there will not be.

To be more precise, Kiwi TCMS used to have export to XML and we have removed it. The reason is that XML, CSV, JSON are all machine readable formats and they are intended to facilitate interaction between different computing systems. The available API interface can be used to achieve the same. Also using the API (via your own script) will give you much more flexibility and control over what kind of information you can export from Kiwi TCMS and push to another system.

That said we're not planning on adding back "export". However if there is something that is missing from the API we can add it.

That said I am interested to know why do you want the "export" functionality ? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: we are planning to migrate from the testopia to KIWI, tetsopia had the feature to download the test cases in csv, excel formats which will be more user friendly and can easily import back.

Comment: The recommended aproach for you will be: 1) download CSV from Testopia; 2) Create a Python script to parse CSV and arrange data the way you like it to appear in Kiwi TCMS 3) Use our API layer to upload the data; 4) Contribute your script to the GitHub repository (I can help you with that) for every body else to benefit.

Comment: See this script for example how to use the API https://gist.github.com/atodorov/f5aed028b6f254d97bcaf93453abe8d2

Comment: This gist URL is invalid. Can you please update it?